# How to debug scala code in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: scala, debugging

My project comprises of both Java and Scala. In Eclipse I use remote debugging and I am able to debug Java code. But I am unable to debug Scala.

Can anyone please help me

Comment: You need to be more specific. What exactly do you do, and what exactly goes wrong?

Answer (score 1):

[ScalaIDE](http://scala-ide.org/index.html) works well for developing mixed Java/Scala projects. It's built on eclipse but has a debugger that is geared more towards Scala code